# How can I have steam install in drive other than C?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move Steam games to another disk?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8176/how-can-i-move-steam-games-to-another-disk)

My C-drive is almost out of space (partly because of Steam games), and I have much bigger space in other drives. However Steam seems to always install in C and now it is refusing to install because not enough space in C. How can I change the Install directory, or have Steam install in directory other than C drive?

Answer (score 2):

You can change steam install directory during installation(since mine is installed on D: disc).

If re installing steam isn't an option there are other ways,the simplest should be using **windows 7 junctions**.

Go to "Start -> Run" and enter "cmd", paste this code in and edit it so the path in the first quotation marks is your "steamapps" folder (empty) on c: disc and second ones the path to your newly created "steamapps" folder on D: disc (containing all data from "steamapps" from C:).

```
mklink /J  "%APPDATA%\..\LocalLow\idSoftware\quakelive\baseq3"   "e:\Quakelive\baseq3"
```

This basically tells computer where to read or write files after getting to the empty folder.

Comment: The path in quotation marks is example from quake live junction.You can edit it for any other folders.

Comment: Source: http://www.quakelive.com/forum/showthread.php?5304-Move-location-of-map-files